# After installing RVM either Rails Server or Git not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, bash, rvm

I broke it again and unfortunately I am not sure why...

**Problem first**

Using the `.bash_profile` that was created during RVM installation Git cannot be found. Adding back the old path exports from mac ports in the `.profile` breaks the rails server by reverting ruby back to 1.8.7

I think I identified

```
/opt/local/bin:
/opt/local/sbin:
```

to be the two directories in the `.bash_profile` that will make Git work but break the new RVM ruby verison.

**Solution**

So here the solution:
I am using a Mac Ports Git version. Thats why it won't run, unless the Mac Ports directories are part of the path. When the Mac Ports directories are sourced after RVM the Mac Ports Ruby Version seem to take precedence over the RVM version.

This will **break**:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
```

This will **work:**

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

Thanks @three for pointing me in the right direction :)

**How I broke it**

Juggeling Ruby and Rails versions around to be in sync with the tutorials I am doing to learn the two, the name RVM kept popping up as a tool to manage those versions more conveniently.

I installed it and and got it to work

```
ruby -v
$ ruby 1.9.2p290 (2011-07-09 revision 32553) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]

rails -v
$ Rails 3.1.3
```

In the process my `.profile` started failing, but I think that is because of the precedence of the `.bash_profile` that was created during the RVM installation. I was expecting trouble but all good so far and everything working, including the rails server.

```
rails s
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 3.1.3 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Call with -d to detach
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2011-12-19 10:16:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2011-12-19 10:16:15] INFO  ruby 1.9.2 (2011-07-09) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
[2011-12-19 10:16:15] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=53018 port=3000
```

Then I wanted to commit to Git, but that all of a sudden doesn't work anymore

```
git
-bash: git: command not found
```

So I compared the `.profile` and `.bash_profile` found that Mac Ports added a line of code to the `.profile` when initially installing ruby, rails and git (sure 100% I used MacPorts for all three)

```
##
# Your previous /Users/username/.profile file was backed up as /Users/username/.profile.macports-saved_2011-10-19_at_08:48:41
##

# MacPorts Installer addition on 2011-10-19_at_08:48:41: adding an appropriate PATH variable for use with MacPorts.
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
# Finished adapting your PATH environment variable for use with MacPorts.
```

If I query the ruby version with this setting I get:

```
ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin10]
```

So my newbie guess is I broke the path variable in the process of installing RVM. If I add the line to the `.bash_profile` git works again, but the rails server doesn't. Notice the ruby version missmatch.:

```
rails s
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/sqlite3-1.3.5/lib/sqlite3/sqlite3_native.bundle: [BUG] Segmentation fault
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-darwin10]

Abort trap
```

The contents of my $PATH when using the Mac Ports PATH exports is:

```
echo $PATH
/opt/local/bin:
/opt/local/sbin:
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:
/Users/username/.rvm/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/X11/bin:
```

On the other hand using the `.bash_profile` as is this is the $PATH contents:

```
echo $PATH
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:
/Users/username/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290@global/bin:
/Users/username/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin:
/Users/username/.rvm/bin:
/usr/bin:
/bin:
/usr/sbin:
/sbin:
/usr/local/bin:
/usr/X11/bin:
```

Looks pretty similar, except for those two directories:

```
/opt/local/bin:
/opt/local/sbin:
```

So my guess is, thats where it breaks... But I have no idea what to do about it.

I am still so new to all of this development, Apple Computers, Unix, Ruby, Rails Stuff :(

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks
TIM

Comment: have you fixed your problem or not ? Can't know for sure from your edits

Answer (score 2, accepted):

put the RVM line after the export PATH for macports so that the rvm binaries for ruby will take precendence

```
export PATH=/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM function
```

Also consider using homebrew instead of macports which is the much slicker version of maintaining *nix tools.

Comment: I tried that, but unfortunately it does not solve the problem. The wrong ruby version (1.8.7 instead of 1.9.2) is still being sourced, when the mac ports exports are in the `.profile`

Comment: you reloaded rvm? `rvm reload`

Comment: I think the problem is that this version of git lives in `/opt/local`/bin/git

Comment: Does the .bash_profile have another PATH variable that is set with different values? If so make sure that it has the :$PATH added to its end. Then close and reopen your Terminal.app session to reload the new values.

Comment: can't post this well formatted for another 7 hours. Will do it then. Thanks for helping me :)

Answer (score 0):

insert this line to .bash_profile:

```
source "$HOME/.profile"
```

before RVM added contents.